# How do I escape the %-character in a vimrc-file?

Tags: escaping, vim

How could I escape the `%` in this example?

```
func! my_func()
  exec "!printf '=%.0s' {1..100}"
endfunc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `shellescape` for any string that is a single argument (not a list of space-separated arguments) and may contains special characters (including space itself):

```
let suspicious_string='=%.0s'
exec "!printf ".shellescape(suspicious_string, 1)." {1..100}"
```